# Excel 2013 - Dynamically reference table by table name

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

### The TLDR

I am looking for information on how to dynamically reference a table in a formula by name.
To be clear, I'm talking about an actual table object, not a named range, and I want to choose which table to select from by the value of a cell.

### Full description

I am working with a series of tables that all share a common formatting (For example, column names: [Level], [Feature], [Notes], etc..

Each table has a distinct, meaningful name: [Cleric], [Fighter], [Druid], etc.

I want to allow a user to type the name of a given table into a cell, and then use INDEX-MATCH to provide information about that table for use in other calculations.

For example:`=INDEX(<??TableName??>, MATCH(Character.Level, <??TableName??>[Feature], 0), 2)`

Is there any way this can be achieved without resorting to code or a custom plugin?

I do see the option of making it one large table that includes all of the separate ones with an additional column like [class], and then dynamically copying that table's information to a second table and performing my look ups there, but that seems kludgey.

*And yes, for those curious, I am working on an excel based character sheet for DnD, 5th ed. I want to get the math ready by the time the OGL standards are out.*

Thank you for your time. I'll only be able to check answers periodically, but I'm hoping to get this done over the weekend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're comfortable with Excel Tables and formulas in general, if so this should help:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/indirect.htm

INDIRECT is used to create a reference *dynamically*. Since a Table name is just a reference, this will work. Simple example:

[image: Example of using INDIRECT to reference a Table in Excel]

Comment: Gah, actually knew about Indirect, but somehow got it in my head that tables were something different and didn't think to try it. Marking as answer over similar response because of helpful link & example pic, plus first. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use nested IF functions, but that's pretty messy.  The other option is to use INDIRECT.  If you use it with CONCATENATE, you can do pretty much what you were asking for.

```
=INDEX(INDIRECT(A12),MATCH(B12,INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(A12,"[Level]")),0),2)
```

See screenshot:

[image]

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for, thank you. (Especially for pertinent example.) I'm afraid I gave the answer to the first responder (With essentially same respose), but thank you.

Comment: Why use CONCATENATE instead of just "&"?